# How to pass arguments into a bat file and use them as parameters for an executable

Tags: windows, git, powershell, batch-file

So we have this DataModel generator that generates apimodels based on existing tables in our db, the problem is the command from the command line is pretty hectic.

example:

```
&'.\Binaries\Tools\General\SAHL.Tools.TestApiModelGenerator.exe' @('-s', 'devo03', '-d', 'db', '-u', 'username', '-p', 'password', '-n', 'dbo', '-o', ‘D:\git\dev', '-i', 'schema,table')
```

I am trying to write a bat file that takes in arguments representing:

- dbServer
- schemas
- tables
- local repository

I only know the absolute basics about writing bat files. I have modified an existing bat file that generates cs classes for each model that was specified in the command line.

Any sort of start would be welcome. I am working from the below script/bat file:

```
**@echo off
IF [%1] == [] (goto error)
IF [%2] == [] (goto error)
IF "%1" == "help" (goto help)
IF NOT [%3] == [] (goto schemas)
%~dp0Build\Tools\Invoke-Build\ib.cmd -File %~dp0Build\Parallel\CodeGeneration.build.ps1 -Task DataModelGeneration -dbSourceServer %1 -properties @{ 'database' = '%2'}
exit
:schemas
%~dp0Build\Tools\Invoke-Build\ib.cmd -File %~dp0Build\Parallel\CodeGeneration.build.ps1 -Task DataModelGeneration -dbSourceServer %1 -properties @{ 'database' = '%2'; 'schemas' = '%3' }
exit
:error
echo.
%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe write-host -foregroundcolor Red "Please provide mandatory parameters [dbSourceServer] and [database]"
:help
echo.
echo Task 
echo ----
echo.
echo help           -- Displays this help menu
echo.
echo GenerateDataModels.bat [dbSourceServer] [database] [schemas]
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo [dbSourceServer]   -- mandatory    - name of the server the database is hosted on
echo [database]     -- mandatory    - name of database
echo [schemas]      -- optional - an inverted-comma-bound, comma delimited list of schemas to include 
echo.
echo (e.g. GenerateDataModels.bat deva03 2am """dbo,debtcounselling""")
echo.
exit**
```

I have got this far,

```
  @echo off

IF [%1] == [] (goto error) --database
IF [%2] == [] (goto error) --engine
IF [%3] == [] (goto error) --schema
IF [%4] == [] (goto error) --tables 
IF [%5] == [] (goto error) --repository
IF "%1" == "help" (goto help)
IF NOT [%3] == [] (goto schemas)

start &'.\Binaries\Tools\General\SAHL.Tools.TestApiModelGenerator.exe' @('-s', %1, '-d', %2, '-u', 'eworkadmin2', '-p', 'W0rdpass', '-n', 'dbo', '-o', %5, '-i', '%4') 
exit

:error
echo.
%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe write-host -foregroundcolor Red "Please provide mandatory parameters [dbSourceServer] and [database]"


:help
echo.
echo Task 
echo ----
echo.
echo help           -- Displays this help menu
echo.
echo GenerateTestApiModels.bat [dbSourceServer] [database] [schemas] [tables] [repository]
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo [dbSourceServer]   -- mandatory    - name of the server the database is hosted on
echo [database]     -- mandatory    - name of database
echo [schemas]      -- mandatory    - an inverted-comma-bound, comma delimited list of schemas to include 
echo [tables] -- mandatory - comma delimited list of table names
echo [repository] -- mandatory (Your local git repository)
echo (e.g. GenerateTestApiModels.bat deva03 2am """dbo,debtcounselling,account""" I:\apollo)
echo.
exit
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you wrapping PowerShell in a batch file?  Why not just use PowerShell?

Comment: For simplicity and re-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to remove the previous steps that tried to build other solutions first. This was the end result:

```
@echo off

IF [%1] == [] (goto error)
IF "%1" == "help" (goto help)
IF [%2] == [] (goto error)
IF [%3] == [] (goto error)
IF [%4] == [] (goto error)

.\Binaries\Tools\General\TestApiModelGenerator.exe -s %1 -d %2 -u username -p password -n %3 -o %cd% -i %4
exit

:error
echo.
%Windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Powershell.exe write-host -foregroundcolor Red "Please provide mandatory parameters [dbSourceServer],[database],[schemas],[tables]"


:help
echo.
echo Task 
echo ----
echo.
echo help           -- Displays this help menu
echo.
echo GenerateTestApiModels.bat [dbSourceServer] [database] [schemas] [tables]
echo ------------------------------------------------------------
echo.
echo [dbSourceServer]   -- mandatory    - name of the server the database is hosted on
echo [database]     -- mandatory    - name of database
echo [schemas]      -- mandatory    - an inverted-comma-bound, comma delimited list of schemas to include 
echo.[tables] -- mandatory - comma delimited list of table names
echo.
exit
```

Comment: if you want to go to `:error` when less than four parameters are given, it's enough to just check `%4` (after checking, `if /i "%1"=="help"` of course)